# Let’s Encrypt で SSL証明書を自動更新したいのですが、cronとsystemdのcertbot.timerの違いについて

Tags: centos, ssl, letsencrypt

**やりたいこと**
・Let’s Encrypt で SSL証明書を自動更新したい

---

**知りたいこと**
・cronとsystemdのcertbot.timerの違い
・それぞれの長所短所
・cronで設定しようとしたら、「systemdのcertbot.timer」でも出来るようなことがネットに書いてありました
・systemdはCentOS7から導入されたと認識しているので、新しい仕組みならこちらの方が何となく良いのかな、と思っているのですが
・従来、cronでしかできなかったことでも、systemd.timerを使えば出来るようになったということでしょうか？

[公式ページ](https://certbot.eff.org/#centosrhel7-nginx)では、cronのみ言及されていますが、systemd.timerは非推奨？

---

**環境**
・CentOS7
・Nginx
・Let’s Encrypt
・certbot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cerbot.timer は systemd のタイマー (Unitの一種) です。

Cron (cronie) の場合はCrontab に書かれたスケジュールにしたがってジョブを起動しますが、systemd の場合は タイマーの設定に従って起動します。
systemd のタイマーには、Cronと同等にカレンダーに合わせて起動させたり、一定間隔で起動、一定間隔でありながらランダムに遅延させたり、ブート後の指定した時間が経過した後に実行などができます。

systemd に統合されているので、起動するジョブを .service として、また、タイマーは .timer というUnit として管理(有効/無効、開始/停止)します。
cgroups の管理下に入れたり、journal でのログ管理などの合わせられるので Cronに比べてより現代的で強力なツールと言えると思います。

その反面、Crontabで1行で設定出来る Cron の手軽さに比べて、設定が面倒な印象があります。systemd特有の強力な機能が不要な場合はCronでも十分です。